ASP.NET Core Hangfire Configurations Docker?
I encounter this error when I send hangfire to Docker:
2024-09-01 17:17:34 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2024-09-01 17:17:34       Storing keys in a directory '/home/app/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
2024-09-01 17:17:34 [14:17:34 WRN] Storing keys in a directory '/home/app/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
2024-09-01 17:18:34 [14:18:34 FTL] Host terminated unexpectedly
2024-09-01 17:18:34 System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27018" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27018", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
2024-09-01 17:18:34  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused [::1]:27018
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.Connect(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2024-09-01T14:18:34.2957867Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2024-09-01T14:18:34.2957870Z" }] }.
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.IClusterExtensions.SelectServerAndPinIfNeeded(ICluster cluster, ICoreSessionHandle session, IServerSelector selector, IReadOnlyCollection`1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(IReadOnlyCollection`1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Create(IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<BulkWrite>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<DeleteOne>b__0(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.DeleteOne(FilterDefinition`1 filter, DeleteOptions options, Func`3 bulkWrite)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.DeleteOne(FilterDefinition`1 filter, DeleteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.DeleteOne(FilterDefinition`1 filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.Migration.MigrationLock.DeleteMigrationLock()
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.Migration.MigrationLock.Dispose()
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoStorage..ctor(IMongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoStorage..ctor(MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings, String databaseName, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UseMongoStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings, String databaseName, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UseMongoStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, String connectionString, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at ara.Jobs.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ConfigureServices>b__1(IGlobalConfiguration configuration) in /src/ara.Jobs/Startup.cs:line 55
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<AddHangfire>b__0(IServiceProvider provider, IGlobalConfiguration config) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.NetCore\HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 40
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddHangfire>b__14(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.NetCore\HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 103
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.ThrowIfNotConfigured(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.NetCore\HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 307
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateBackgroundJobServerHostedService(IServiceProvider provider, JobStorage storage, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, BackgroundJobServerOptions options) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.NetCore\HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 241
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<AddHangfireServerInner>b__0(IServiceProvider provider) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.NetCore\HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 194
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
2024-09-01 17:18:34    at Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/ara.Jobs/Program.cs:line 16

Database Compose
version: "3.7"

services:

  ara-mongo-db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'ara'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: '***'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: '***'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

  arajob-mongo-db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'arajob'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: '***'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: '***'
    ports:
      - 27018:27017  
    volumes:
      - arajob_mongodb_data:/data/db


volumes:
  mongodb_data:
  arajob_mongodb_data:


Hangfire Asp.net Core
Dockerfile
# Base image for the runtime environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5130
EXPOSE 5131

# Image to build the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src

# Copy project files
COPY ["./ara.Jobs/ara.Jobs.csproj", "ara.Jobs/"]
COPY ["ara.Application/ara.Application.csproj", "ara.Application/ara.Application/"]
COPY ["ara.Cache/ara.Cache.csproj", "ara.Cache/"]

COPY ["ara.Domain/ara.Domain.csproj", "ara.Domain/"]
COPY ["ara.SharedKernel/ara.SharedKernel.csproj", "ara.SharedKernel/"]
COPY ["ara.Framework/EventsourcingRepository/ara.EventSourcingRepository.csproj", "ara.Framework/EventsourcingRepository/"]
COPY ["ara.Framework/QueryRepository/ara.QueryRepository.csproj", "ara.Framework/QueryRepository/"]
COPY ["ara.Framework/EmailService/ara.EmailService.csproj", "ara.Framework/EmailService/"]
COPY ["ara.Framework/Authentication/ara.Authentication.csproj", "ara.Framework/Authentication/"]
COPY ["ara.ObjectStorage/ara.ObjectStorage.csproj", "ara.ObjectStorage/"]

# Restore, build and publish
RUN dotnet restore "ara.Jobs/ara.Jobs.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ara.Jobs"
RUN dotnet build "ara.Jobs.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ara.Jobs.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Final image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ara.Jobs.dll"]


Docker-Compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  ara-jobs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release
    ports:
      - "5130:5130"
      - "5131:5131"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

When I send hangfire to docker I encounter this error. Can you help me? What should I do?

What's your connection string for mongo db from your jobs app? Looks like it's ::1 localhost - that's not correct, as it's referring to the container the job app is running in, not the host machine running mongo. You might want something like host.docker.internal if running on windows.

How to make host.docker.internal

You don't have to make it, it's a built in feature of Docker desktop. The alternative would be to have relevant containers connect to the same network and reference it via the container name arajob-mongo-db, but that's more complicated.

I will rent a docker server, it will be in different containers, I need to try it locally first, can you give me a sample code on how I can proceed?
